# how to search through an XMLfile stored in URL in android app

Tags: java, android, xml, url

in my app i have a button named Search, When the user clicks the button, i want to show the list of contents stored in an URL like   http://ss.com/add/search?

the url is to be a server where lot of entries are been registered and stored.

When we get into the URL in a website it looks like an XML file.

`<Search>
<Search>
<id>4</id>
<First_name>Egg</First_name>
<Last_name>Xfg</Last_name>
<latitude>12.90</latitude>
<longitude>45.100937</longitude>
<Datebirth>Jan 5, 2000</Datebirth>
<Dateofresting>Nov 3, 1998</Dateofresting>
<Location>ksdkvkjsjkvbkjfbvkfdvfd jvk</Location>
</Search>`

Like this the url contains few hundred data.
Among this i want to show only the first name of all the users who have been registered. in my mobile.

Can anyone help me to do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you need parser go thorugh following link

http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html